# Regular Expression to match equal words in a certain positions of a string

Tags: regex

I have a number of strings:

```
...somedata... value1='555', value2='666', ...somedata...
...somedata... value1='333', value2='333', ...somedata...
...somedata... value1='123', value2='456', ...somedata...
```

Is there a way to match strings that has equal values in `value1` and `value2`?

For example `value1='x'` `value2='y'`, where `x == y`.

Comment: Yes there might be . . .I guess by capturing the first value and using capturing group to match second value. Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/tV4cH3/2)

Comment: i suppose you should specify more info. why you want to do like this? why is it saved as strings? show your proper code

Comment: Yes, of course, I can compare the results outside of the regex itself. Just wondering if there's a way to do it inside somehow.

Comment: @Shri, I don't think there's much to add here. I would like this question to be helpful to others, who has no control over the process that generates these strings.

Comment: ▲ for the question. I never actually thought of comparing numerical values in regex.

Comment: @noob Yes! And not only numerical. Any character class you put instead of `\d`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you are trying to do is match both `values`. In terms of regex we will call this `pattern`. I have a rough solution which might be extended.

**Regex:** `.*value1=\'(\d*)\'.*value2=\'\1\'.*`

**Explanation:**

- What am doing here is capturing the `value1` and expecting the `value2` to be same `pattern`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tV4cH3/2)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you very much! I was missing something here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
value1='([0-9]*)', value2='\1'
```

I think you'll probably want to read about [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) and try them out on one of the online regex testers [like this one](https://regex101.com/)

EDIT:
BTW, if you weren't already planning on doing it, you are probably going to want to use the /g modifier at the end of the above regex so that it returns all of the results that match that pattern and not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Use **awk**

Not sure which regexp to use without knowing your input data, but output command would be

```
if $leftNum == $rightNum print $whateverUwant
```